# How to figure out the "install" step in a debian package?

Tags: apt, nvidia, dpkg, lxc

I am running `privileged lxc container` on `Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS` host.
I have a nvidia graphics card on my hardware and therefore I installed `nvidia 367.44` graphics driver on host machine.

Now, inside the `lxc` container I wanted to install the libraries pertaining to this version of nvidia driver. But since the `.deb` package at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-367/367.44-0ubuntu0.16.04.1/+build/10722926
modifies the `initrd` and I don't want the installation inside the container to mess with the kernel/initrd image of the host system, so I thought that I would extract the libraries from the debian package file and install it manually using scripts.

Inside the `control` part of the `.deb` file listed above, following are found:

```
conffiles
control
md5sums
postinst
postrm
preinst
prerm
shlibs
triggers
```

My question is, where is the install script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to worry about modifying the initrd inside the container, unless you're giving access to the container to modify the initrd explicitly. Just install the package and it should work fine.

There is no "script" in the .deb which describes where to install files to, or how. The tarball of contents is simply unpacked in the root directory. The scripts which update the initrd are likely *postinst* and *prerm* or *postrm* in the package.

Comment: can you explain a bit more ? While installing the same nvidia package on host system, I saw that it modifies the initrd image. Wouldn't it try/actually modify the initrd inside the container too. And since it is a `privileged` container, that would mean host initrd

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding _privileged_ in this context, but I'm pretty sure that is not what it means; otherwise it would not exactly be a container. The /boot partition is not shared to the container by default.

Comment: Wouldn't the install script fail since it can't update the `initrd`?

Comment: It's possible, but it won't overwrite your host initrd, which is what your question was about. Why not try it and see what happens?